# Is there a way to create merge request to multiple branches?

Tags: git, gitlab

Is there any way to create two merge requests at once?
For example:
there is a branch called "fix-bugs", and now we want to create MR to branch master and production in a single command. Is it possible?

Comment: No, you will have to do that many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that's possible in GitLab. As alternatives to make the process easier, you can:

- [Cherry pick](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/cherry_pick_changes.html) the changes from the original MR into the other branch
- Do not delete your "fix-bugs" branch after the MR has been merged into the first branch. Then resubmit the "fix-bugs" branch against the second branch.